# Javafx: how to fill a TilePane with circles and add an event handler to each one

Tags: java, events, geometry, tile

I tryed with this code but it is not working:

```
public class Scacchiera extends Application {

    TilePane root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = new TilePane();
        root.setPrefColumns(4);
        root.setPrefRows(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            Circle c = new Circle(i);
            c.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Circle clicked");
                }
            });
            root.getChildren().add(c);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Why? Can you help me? I am not sure what is the problem but may be my events handler dies with the `for` cicle..

Answer (score 0):

Circles are just shapes, they don't have actions like controls.

What you want to do is is handle an [`onMouseClicked`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onMouseClickedProperty) event to your circle:

```
// java 8
circle.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> System.out.println("Mouse Clicked!"));
```

Comment: And what if i'd like to change color or radius of the circle?

Comment: Then change them; fill and radius don't seem related to your original question.